# Modal with Tailwindcss and Alpine JS

Tags: phoenix-framework, tailwind-css, alpine.js

I am trying to implement a modal for my Phoenix LiveView project. But got a problem - my modal is on screen, but I still can use tab to interact with elements on my page. Is this something wrong with my tailwindcss code? To open my modal I use the route: "user/change_email". And my LiveView modal keeps the state of show

```
<div>
  <div id={"#{@id}"}
  phx-hook="Modal"
  x-data={"{ open: #{@show} }"}
  x-init={"() => {
              $nextTick(() => $refs.modalRightButton.focus())
              $watch('open', isOpen => {
                console.log('WATCH OPEN = ' + isOpen)
                if (!isOpen) {
                  modalHook.modalClosing(#{@leave_duration})
                }
              })
            }"}
  @keydown.escape.window="if (connected) open = false"
  x-show="open"
  x-cloak>
  <div class="z-50 fixed bottom-0 inset-x-0 px-4 pb-4 sm:inset-0 sm:flex sm:items-center sm:justify-center">
  <!-- BACKDROP -->
  <div x-show="open"
      x-cloak
      x-transition:enter={"ease-out duration-#{@enter_duration}"}
      x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0"
      x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100"
      x-transition:leave={"ease-in duration-#{@leave_duration}"}
      x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100"
      x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0"
      class="fixed inset-0 transition-opacity">
   <div class={"absolute inset-0  #{@background_color} #{@background_opacity}"}></div>
  </div>
  <div x-show="open"
      x-cloak
      @click.away="if (connected) open = false"
      x-transition:enter={"ease-out duration-#{@enter_duration}"}
      x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
      x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
      x-transition:leave={"ease-in duration-#{@leave_duration}"}
      x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
      x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
      class="bg-white rounded-lg overflow-hidden shadow-xl transform transition-all sm:max-w-lg sm:w-full"
      role="dialog"
      aria-modal="true"
      aria-labelledby="modal-headline"
      aria-describedby="modal-description">
   <div class="bg-white px-4 pt-5 pb-4 sm:p-6 sm:pb-4">
     <div class="sm:flex sm:items-start">
       <div class="mx-auto flex-shrink-0 flex items-center justify-center h-12 w-12 rounded-full bg-red-100 sm:mx-0 sm:h-10 sm:w-10">
       <!-- SVG el -->
         <svg class="h-6 w-6 text-red-600"
              fill="none"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              stroke="currentColor">
           <path stroke-linecap="round"
                 stroke-linejoin="round"
                 stroke-width="2"
                 d="M12 9v2m0 4h.01m-6.938 4h13.856c1.54 0 2.502-1.667 1.732-3L13.732 4c-.77-1.333-2.694-1.333-3.464 0L3.34 16c-.77 1.  333.192 3 1.732 3z" />
         </svg>
       </div>
       <div class="mt-3 text-center sm:mt-0 sm:ml-4 sm:text-left">
         <h3 class={"text-lg leading-6 font-medium #{@title_color}"}
                   id="modal-headline">
                     <%= @title %>
                   </h3>
         <div class="mt-2">
           <p class={"text-sm leading-5 #{@body_color}"}
              id="modal-description">
             <%= @body %>
           </p>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="bg-gray-50 px-4 py-3 sm:px-6 sm:flex sm:flex-row-reverse">
     <span class="flex w-full rounded-md shadow-sm sm:ml-3 sm:w-auto">
       <button type="button"
               phx-click="right-button-click"
               phx-target={"#{@id}"}
               class={"inline-flex justify-center w-full rounded-md border border-transparent px-4 py-2 bg-#{@right_button_color}-600 text-base leading-6 font-medium text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-#{@right_button_color}-500   focus:outline-none     focus:border-#{@right_button_color}-700 focus:shadow-outline-#{@right_button_color} transition ease-in-out  duration-150 sm:text-sm sm:leading-5"}
               x-ref="modalRightButton"
               @click="if (connected) open = false">
         <%= @right_button %>
       </button>
     </span>
     <%= if @left_button != nil do %>
     <span class="mt-3 flex w-full rounded-md shadow-sm sm:mt-0 sm:w-auto">
       <button type="button"
               phx-click="left-button-click"
               phx-target={"#{@id}"}
               class="inline-flex justify-center w-full rounded-md border border-gray-300 px-4 py-2 bg-white text-base leading-6 font-medium text-gray-700 shadow-sm hover:text-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-300 focus:shadow-outline-blue transition ease-in-out duration-150 sm:text-sm sm:leading-5"
               @click="if (connected) open = false">
         <%= @left_button %>
       </button>
     </span>
     <% end %>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <template id={"connection-#{@id}"} phx-hook="ConnectionStatus"></template>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your CSS. Alpine.js can handle this for you with the Trap plugin: https://alpinejs.dev/plugins/trap

In your example that would be something like:

```html
 <div
   ...
   x-show="open"
   x-trap.inert.noscroll="open"
   ...>
```